# Is it the State-Trie or the State-Tree?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

This affects the tags [state-tree](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-tree) and [state-tree-pruning](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-tree-pruning).

Vitalik Buterin [refers in his blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/06/26/state-tree-pruning/) to "**State Tree Pruning**".

Gavin Wood [more recently talks about](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/issues/208) the "**State Trie Pruning**".

So, what is it, the the *State-Trie* or the *State-Tree*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since also Christian Reitwiessner in his [most recent post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/12/ethereum-dev-update-c-roadmap/) also refers to **state trie pruning**, I would suggest to rename the tags using the term **trie**.

The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) also explains why trie is the more correct term.

Update: Tag is now [state-trie-pruning](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-trie-pruning).

Comment: ...and `state-tree-pruning` is a synonym.

Answer (score 1):

Tree is the more general term; trie is a more precise term technically since it's a more specific type of tree...  Trie is more nitpicky.  I think using the general term, "tree", is better for tagging purposes and is accurate enough.